# Is npm the right place to publish a standalone app

Tags: node.js, npm, publishing

I'm working on a application using node.js and I'm wondering whether I should add it to the npm registry so that it's easy to install. It's not a module that you would be able to use, which is what the majority of packages on npm are.

If npm isn't the right place to publish it, is there another place I can publish it so that users don't have to use the `git clone; npm install` method to install it.

Comment: You can store your releases on a server and allow people to download the app through a website

Comment: Could I use github for the server, and create a github pages as the website?

Comment: There is something called Github Pages. You should check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to publish your application is to create a website and store your releases on it. Fortunately github offers a way to create a website out of your github repository. For more information you can go to this [link](https://pages.github.com/)

Forcing users to download your application through `npm` is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't see why `npm` is not the good place to do it. That's exactly what `npm` was designed for.

Comment: @Danosaure because users need to have `npm` only to download the application. Do you use `npm` to download skype? Users don't need source code, just the app.

Comment: This is a node.js application. You are not comparing the same things, so it's an unfair question. Do you npm install `grunt-cli` to use `grunt`? Yes. So keep your context relevant to the question.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, we are talking about releases, not source code, so people utilizing the app are just users. I don't see why anyone would want to install node.js only to download an app. The question specifically states: "so that users don't have to use the git clone; npm install method to install it." I don't see how you can avoid this step with `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

I do that all the time (publish to npmjs), but I put it under an organization.

Check out [NPM org](https://www.npmjs.com/features)

You can make your code available in the path by setting the [bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) section of `package.json`.

All the user now needs to do to use your application would be:

```
npm install -g @your-org/your-app
```

and given a proper setup of the `bin` section above mentioned, you could allow the user to run your app (again, I'm not sure what type of application we are talking about). This works for any type.

If you do not wish to install it globally, the executable would be available in `node_modules/.bin/your-app-name-as-in-bin-of-package-json`

Please explain more what your application does so that we can help you better.

Comment: Could you please explain this more

Comment: I'm sorry, which part would you like me to elaborate? The npm org or how i reuse them?

Comment: Could you elaborate on both parts

Comment: Just like other packages on npm, you install them and use them. Maybe you can describe more in details what your application does. There seems to be a misconception that everything nodejs is a webapp.